# How to turn a spatial plot in R into an ArcGIS layer

Tags: r, mapping, raster, arcgis, shapefile

So I hope I can clearly communicate my issue. Since I'm fairly new to R and ArcGIS I may miss some obvious things.

Basically, I'm using R to process spatial data to make a canopy height model and detect tree tops. That parts fine. I then make a watershed segment plot using forestTools package, and visually it looks great, but how do I export that as a file I can add into ArcGIS?

I'll copy some of the code that goes into what I'm discussing.
Basically, I just followed this guide's supplemental material to get the tree detection https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/geo-2020-0290/html?lang=en.

With that done, I then used the forestTools package to creat an interesting segmentation polygon grid on the map. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ForestTools/versions/0.2.5/topics/mcws

This is quickly the plotting code to get visualized what I want.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y0EF.png

This is what the map looks like with those plotted.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdfl6.png

The layer that I want to bring solo to ArcGIS is that last plot the mcws one. I'll show a pic of that as well here.
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PKfk.png

Is there a way that I can export that as a .shp or .tif?

Any help would be wonderful and much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nvmd I figured it out.

What you have to do is use the Raster package to export a shapefile.

raster::shapefile(site2_ttops,"Products/site2plot_ttops.shp")